# How to identify MIME type based on content after renaming the file Using JAVA

Tags: java, excel, file-upload, file-type

I am trying to identify the MIME type using JAVA program, based on content.

For example:

I have a file **abc.exe**, i have renamed it to **abc.xls** and try to find the MIME type for the file, It supposed to show 'Application' But it showed as 'Excel' type. Can someone help me on finding the actual file type based on content?

Comment: can you show me your screenshot?

Comment: You can use [URLConnection class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html). e.g `URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(inputStream)`